# How to split \n for create a dataframe

Tags: python

I have a string like this:

```
response= (b"Year,City,Sport,Discipline,NOC,Event,Event gender,Medal\n1924,Chamonix,Skating,Figure skating,AUT,individual,M,Silver\n1924,Chamonix,Skating,Figure skating,AUT,individual,W,Gold\n1924,Chamonix,Skating,Figure skating,AUT,pairs,X,Gold\n1924,Chamonix,Bobsleigh,Bobsleigh,BEL,four-man,M,Bronze\n1924,Chamonix,Ice Hockey,Ice Hockey,CAN,ice hockey,M,Gold\n1924,Chamonix,Biathlon,Biathlon,FIN,military patrol,M,Silver\n1924")
```

I need to make a Dataframe:

```
data3=str(response, 'utf-8')## For convert byte string to a unicode string
cols=data3.split(",")
cols
print(cols)


['Year', 'City', 'Sport', 'Discipline', 'NOC', 'Event', 'Event gender', 'Medal\n1924', 'Chamonix', 'Skating', 'Figure skating', 'AUT', 'individual', 'M', 'Silver\n1924', 'Chamonix', 'Skating', 'Figure skating', 'AUT', 'individual', 'W', 'Gold\n1924', 'Chamonix'....]
```

I want to separate `Gold\n1924` --> `Gold, 1924`

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Think about it, if only the `'\n'` was a `', '` from the first place you wouldn't need to change anything.... You can actually do that using [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)...

Comment: why don't you split by newlines (`\n`) first? Then you'll have each year as a part of a list. You can join these lists later :)

Answer (score 0):

```
data = str(response, 'utf-8').split(',')
data = [x.replace('\n', ', ') for x in data]
```

or

```
data = str(response, 'utf-8').replace('\n', ', ').split(',')
```